# How to implement wildcards for window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, html, url, window.location

I have the following code and I would like to make the function work on any URL containing "blog" instead of a specific URL. Please help me with the correct syntax, thanks.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  if (window.location.pathname != '/home/legal-documentation' &&
    window.location.pathname != '/home/blog/australian-business-news'
  ) {
    erOpenLoginRegisterbox(jQuery);
  }
  return false;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Feedback: rightly or wrongly, the wording of your questions matters on Stack Overflow. "Please help me with the correct syntax" strikes me as _an unresearched request for free work_. If you want to get the best out of this platform, show what you have tried, and what specific problem you had with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). It will return -1 if it does *not* find the string it is passed, so testing for -1 seems to correlate with your approach.  Furthermore, to be on the safe side, in case you also want to exclude blog in a case-insensitive manner (in other words, you want to test for Blog, blog, BLOG, etc.), I refer to pathname as though it were uppercase ([`String.prototype.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)), and then compare it to 'BLOG'

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.location.pathname.toUpperCase().indexOf('BLOG') === -1) {
        erOpenLoginRegisterbox(jQuery);
    }
    return false;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). These are used to match a certain combination of characters, in your case, you can use `String.prototype.match()` in order to find Strings containing the word "blog" using this RegEx:

```
/blog/gi
```

or, in your function:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.location.pathname.match(/blog/gi)) {
        erOpenLoginRegisterbox(jQuery);
    }
    return false;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd link](https://xkcd.com/1171/).

Comment: There's at some point going to be a XKCD Comic for every situation